# ionic v1 cards detail change using an array with pointer from local storage

Tags: angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm trying to call an array item into a ionic card, the text in the card should adapt when there has been a change in my local storage variable x. This changes when a button is pressed.
Unfortunately all the tutorials I find with the arrays are using ng-repeat which doesn't work well with ionic cards and the other tutorials are lists that you click then a new page is opened in the existing tab.
I'm looking only to change the text in a card when a button is pressed that changes my counter.

Be great if someone could show me how to adapt the html and app.js to achieve this.

Thx in advance.

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngStorage'])

.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $localStorage) 
{
    var Abby = [
                { id: 0, name: 'Hello' },
                { id: 1, name: 'Hello 2' },
                { id: 2, name: 'Hello 3' },
                { id: 3, name: 'Hello 4' }
               ];

    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        x: 42

    });
    $scope.deleteX = function() {
      delete $localStorage.x;
    };
    $scope.deleteY = function() {
      delete $localStorage.y;
    };
})
`
```

Html:

```
`
<ion-content class="padding" >


   <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button> <button ng-click="$storage.y = $storage.y + 1">{{$storage.y}}</button> 
        <p></p>
        <button ng-click="deleteX()">Clear x</button> | <button ng-click="deleteY()">Clear y</button>
        <img src="./img/ionic{{$storage.x}}.png">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-body">

            {{$Abby.{{$storage.x}}}}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
`
```